# Sql developer custom connection string

Tags: oracle, database-connection, connection-string, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to use custom connection string in Oracle sql developer to connect?

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=147.22.109.218)(port=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=147.22.109.219)(port=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=147.22.109.220)(port=1521)))
(FAILOVER=on)(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=cmphpd)))
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do, please make question clear

Comment: @Exhausted- My application has more than one database in our regression environment. For load balancing between databases, I chose to use advanced 'custom JDBC URL' to connect database. E.g. custom JDBC URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=147.22.109.218)(port=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=147.22.109.219)(port=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=147.22.109.220)(port=1521)))
(FAILOVER=on)(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=cmphpd))). If you see it has more than one database address in the URL.

Comment: use the dropdown Connection Type to find jdbc URL. select that and then enter your URL into the textbox below.

Answer (score 5):

To us a TNS connection string, in the *New / Select Database Connection* window where you configure the connection:

1. Set *Connection Type* to *TNS*
2. Under the *Details* tab select *Connect Identifier*
3. Put the connection string into the text box next to *Connect Identifier*
4. Click *Test* if you'd like, to make sure it works
5. Click *Save*

Similarly, under *Connection Type* there also seems to be an option for a custom JDBC URL if that's what you prefer.

(Instructions and screenshot from version 19.4, in case it makes a difference)

[image]

Comment: Had the same problem, connection type "TNS" did not work for me as sql developer wanted the OCI libraries and I didn't have them. However, setting the connection type to "custom JDBC", having a connection string like jdbc:oracle:thin:@(...) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@147.22.109.220:1521/cmphpd
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the best and complete instructions I've found.
https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc,-tlsv12,-jks-or-oracle-wallets

Below are the steps which I took to fix this issue:

1. Install JCE (following the instructions in Readme) - [JCE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)
2. Add below lines in build.gradle

   `System.setProperty('oracle.net.ssl_version', '1.2')
   System.setProperty('oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites', '(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)')
   System.setProperty('oracle.net.tns_admin', './lib')
   System.setProperty('oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match', 'true')`
3. Setup db connection like

   `String connString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=
      (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=prodHost)))
   (connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME=ORCL)))";
   OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
   ods.setURL(connString);
   ods.setUser("scott");
   ods.setPassword("tiger");
   Connection conn = ods.getConnection();`

Comment: It would be better to brief the content since one day the link can be outdated